# Text does not appear when hovering over image

Tags: html, css

When you hover over the image, the place where it should go down from top to bottom does not work and the image does not grow when I hover over it.

Here I want the place labeled "downmen" to go down with a top-down effect. At the same time I want the picture I hover over to grow a little.
As a result, when both hover over the image, I want one to go down from the top and the other to make the image grow.
Note I used bootstrap 5 while doing these.

```css
.section-two-card-inner-two {
  position: relative;
}

.section-two-card-inner-two .downmen {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  padding: 2% 10%;
}

.section-two-card-inner-two:hover .downmen {
  display: block;
}

.section-two-card-inner-two .downmen img {
  height: 55px;
}

.card-title-head {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.section-two-card-inner-two a {
  padding-top: 15%;
}

.section-two-card .card-title {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.section-two-card .card-text {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'League Spartan', sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.section-two-card .card-text:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" />
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-lg-2 section-two-card m-0">
  <div class="col p-2 section-two-card-inner ">
    <div class="card bg-dark text-white section-two-card-inner-two ">
      <div class="downmen  d-flex text-secondary align-items-center ">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/55" alt=".." class="img-fluid rounded-circle me-3">
        <div class="col-10">
          <h4 class="fw-normal">Posted by <strong>admin</strong></h4>
          <h4 class="fw-normal">August 27, 2025</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt="" class="rounded-4 border-0 img-fluid">
      <div class="card-img-overlay p-4 p-sm-5  border border-0 ">
        <div class="d-flex card-title-head">
          <h5 class="card-title  text-secondary">Most Read </h5>
          <h4 class="card-title ms-3"><i class="bi bi-clock fs-5 text-white me-2"></i> 6 min read</h4>
        </div>
        <p class="card-text">This will help you become the first and strengthen your position</p>
        <a href="#" class="card-title text-decoration-none text-white d-flex">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right ms-2 fs-4"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only `:hover` I see in your CSS, is `.section-two-card .card-text:hover` - so how do you expect that to affect your image? `.card-text` is a paragraph containing only text.

Comment: Third from the top in CSS 
'.section-two-card-inner-two:hover .downmen {
  display: block;
}'
I guess you haven't seen this coding. I'm trying to do what is in the "Lastest news" section on this site. https://mobirise.com/extensions/newsm4/technews/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [example](https://mobirise.com/extensions/newsm4/technews/#) provides everything you need. Just use your browser to inspect the initial state of the relevant elements (`.card_post`) and that after forcing hover on `.item-wrapper`.

The only lingering issue is that the hover state is triggered on an element which is larger than the image. That could be refined with layout adjustments.

```css
.section-two-card-inner-two {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; /* new */
}

.section-two-card-inner-two img {
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0.4s; /* new */
}

.section-two-card-inner-two:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1); /* new */
}

.section-two-card-inner-two .downmen {
  opacity: 0; /* new */
  transform: translateY(-10px); /* new */
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0.4s; /* new */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  padding: 2% 10%;
}

.section-two-card-inner-two:hover .downmen {
  opacity: 1; /* new */
  transform: translateY(0); /* new */
}

.section-two-card-inner-two .downmen img {
  height: 55px;
}

.card-title-head {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.section-two-card-inner-two a {
  padding-top: 15%;
}

.section-two-card .card-title {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.section-two-card .card-text {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'League Spartan', sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.section-two-card .card-text:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" />
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-lg-2 section-two-card m-0">
  <div class="col p-2 section-two-card-inner ">
    <div class="card bg-dark text-white section-two-card-inner-two ">
      <div class="downmen  d-flex text-secondary align-items-center ">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/55" alt=".." class="img-fluid rounded-circle me-3">
        <div class="col-10">
          <h4 class="fw-normal">Posted by <strong>admin</strong></h4>
          <h4 class="fw-normal">August 27, 2025</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt="" class="rounded-4 border-0 img-fluid">
      <div class="card-img-overlay p-4 p-sm-5  border border-0 ">
        <div class="d-flex card-title-head">
          <h5 class="card-title  text-secondary">Most Read </h5>
          <h4 class="card-title ms-3"><i class="bi bi-clock fs-5 text-white me-2"></i> 6 min read</h4>
        </div>
        <p class="card-text">This will help you become the first and strengthen your position</p>
        <a href="#" class="card-title text-decoration-none text-white d-flex">Read More <i class="bi bi-arrow-right ms-2 fs-4"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```